# JQuery - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, uncaught-exception

I have the following code with JQuery and i get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error in line `var nueva fila = $(document.createElement('tr'));`.

```
function add_fields_for_membresias(event) {
var usuario_id = $('#cbx_miembro').val();

var usuario_nombre = $('#cbx_miembro :selected').text();

var rol_value = $('#cbx_rol').val();

var posicionRolEnLaTabla = $('#tb_membresias tbody tr').length;

var columna_usuarioNombre = $('td');

columna_usuarioNombre.html = usuario_nombre;

var columna_rol = $('td');

columna_rol.html("<input id='equipo_membresias_attributes_" + posicionRolEnLaTabla + "_usuario_id' name='equipo[membresias_attributes][" + posicionRolEnLaTabla + "][usuario_id]' readonly='readonly' type='hidden' value='" + usuario_id + "\'>" +
"<input id='equipo_membresias_attributes_" + posicionRolEnLaTabla + "_supervisor' name='equipo[membresias_attributes][" + posicionRolEnLaTabla + "][administrador]' readonly='readonly' type='hidden' value='" + rol_value + "\'>" +
"<input id='equipo_membresias_attributes_" + posicionRolEnLaTabla + "_id' name='equipo[membresias_attributes][" + posicionRolEnLaTabla + "][id]' readonly='readonly' type='hidden'>" +
"<input id='equipo_membresias_attributes_" + posicionRolEnLaTabla + "__destroy' name='equipo[membresias_attributes][" + posicionRolEnLaTabla + "][_destroy]' type='hidden' value='false'>");

var columna_opciones = $('td');

columna_opciones.html("<input class=\"btn btn-mini\" onclick=\"remove_fields(this);\" type=\"button\" value=\"Quitar\">");

var nueva fila = $('tr');

nueva_fila.append(columna_usuarioNombre);
nueva_fila.append(columna_rol);
nueva_fila.append(columna_opciones);

$('#tb_membresias tbody').append(nueva_fila);
}
```

Somebody can help me?

I tryed also with:

```
"<input class=\"btn btn-mini\" onclick=\"remove_fields(this);\" type=\"button\" value=\"Quitar\">"
```

Comment: Where specifically are you getting this error?

Comment: The error doesn't belong to the posted code.

Comment: Looks fine to me. check here http://jsfiddle.net/J6BWc/

Comment: Edit: I posted the entire function and put in where line get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
$('tr');
```

to create a `tr` element, instead of

```
$(document.createElement('tr'));
```

because, you are using `jQuery` and `jQuery` will take care of that. To create any element using `jQuery` you just supply the name of that `element/tag`, for example, to create a `td` you can use

```
var td = $('td');
```

for a div, just use

```
var div = $('div');
```

That's it.

**Update:** In your code you have

```
var nueva fila = $(document.createElement('tr'));
```

here, `nueva fila` is not a valid variable name, it should be a single word, without any spaces, like

```
var nuevafila = $('tr');
```

or you can use

```
var nueva_fila = $('tr');
```

Check [Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables) on MDN.

Comment: Thanks, i do it, but i keep getting the same error in the same line.